# FB.Canvas.scrollTo Not working inside iframe in Facebook tab page

Tags: facebook, iframe, canvas, scroll

I would like to have a "go to top" link inside an iFrame tab page in the new Facebook timeline, have tried to use FB.Canvas.scrollTo as follows but not working.  Any pointers greated appreciated!

```
<body style="overflow: hidden">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

  // Init the SDK upon load
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'myAppID', 
      channelUrl : 'my_channel.html', 
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

 document.getElementById('go_to_top').addEventListener('click', function(){
      FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
    }); 

  <div id="goToTop">
     <img border=0 src ="aPicForClicking.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem. In the application settings set Canvas Height to Fixed.
Then FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0) works fine;

Comment: Thanks for the tip! (don't have enough reputation to +! yet..)

Answer (score 0):

Canvas do not throw an error but also do not function when the iframe is within the content of another iframe.

IE. nested iframes are not supported for API calls.